# Emptying an object of arrays with a loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to empty an object of arrays using a loop:

```
this.payload =  {
   'names': ['john','chris'],
   'addresses': ['10 king street', '20 king street'],
};

for (const [prop, items] of Object.entries(this.payload)) {
       items = [];
}
```

I want to be left with:

```
this.payload =  {
   'names': [],
   'addresses': [],
};
```

But my loop does not seem to change the value.

Comment: `items = []` is creating a global variable, and overriding it on every loop. Try `this.payload[prop] = []`

Comment: @elclanrs: Not with the above. Actually, the above should be failing with an error that you can't assign to a `const`.

Comment: maybe another question arise, do you have a reference of `this.payload.names` somwhere in the code and you need to keep the reference? or do you need **after** emtying the old content, or should it follow with the empty array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting this.payload[prop] = []
Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var payload =  {
   'names': ['john','chris'],
   'addresses': ['10 king street', '20 king street'],
};

for (const prop of Object.keys(this.payload)) {
   payload[prop] = []
}

console.log(payload);
```

Comment: In which case, there's no reason to use `Object.entries` and destructuring assignment. One would simply use `const prop of Object.keys(this.payload)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yup that is also an option. Updated my answer. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

With assignment to an object(/array) variable, you *switch* that variable to another object reference, not touching the originally assigned object.

Instead of making a new array, unrelated to the existing one, like you do now (`items = []`), *mutate* the `items` array, like this:

```
items.length = 0;
```

Comment: This doesnt effect the original object.

Comment: @panthro: What makes you think that? `items` isn't a **copy** of the array, it's a **reference** to the array. Modifying the array's state modifies the array's state.

Comment: When I log it the values are still there.

Comment: @panthro: Not if we drop trincot's and Nina's code into your code in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I see how that could look confusing. I took your advice. ;-)

Comment: Indeed, I tried to keep it simple and focus on the assignment only.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep the array reference and set the length to zero, instead of assigning a new empty array, which keeps the array for the local reference.

```js
var payload =  {
   'names': ['john','chris'],
   'addresses': ['10 king street', '20 king street'],
};

for (const [prop, items] of Object.entries(this.payload)) {
    items.length = 0;
}

console.log(payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you use `this.payload.names` or `this.payload.addresses` in another place of your code, if these *participants* need to be aware of the array being cleared, you will need to keep the array reference, use `array.length = 0`.

> Whenever the length property is changed, every property whose name is
>   an array index whose value is not smaller than the new length is
>   automatically deleted.

```js
var payload = {
  'names': ['john', 'chris'],
  'addresses': ['10 king street', '20 king street'],
};

const names = payload.names;
const addresses = payload.addresses;

for (const items of Object.values(this.payload)) {
  items.length = 0;
}

console.log(payload);

console.log(names, addresses); // [] []
```

---

However, if you do not need to keep references, you can create a new array and let the garbage collector take care of the old value.

```js
var payload = {
  'names': ['john', 'chris'],
  'addresses': ['10 king street', '20 king street'],
};

const names = payload.names;
const addresses = payload.addresses;

for (const prop of Object.keys(this.payload)) {
  payload[prop] = [];
}

console.log(payload);

console.log(names, addresses); // ["john", "chris"] ["10 king street", "20 king street"]
```